# Grails 3.3.2 Spring Security Code & CAS

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-plugin

I am getting the following exception after entering my user name and pw into my CAS login form, Grails 3.3.2 app.

```
Configuring Spring Security Core ...
... finished configuring Spring Security Core


Configuring Spring Security CAS ...
... finished configuring Spring Security CAS

Grails application running at http://localhost:8089 in environment: development
2018-05-22 13:59:47.395 DEBUG --- [nio-8089-exec-2] o.j.c.c.session.SingleSignOutHandler     : Recording session for token ST-1553-4NR7XWRPXGioiJXs9oLd-cas-01.mydomain.com
2018-05-22 13:59:47.395 DEBUG --- [nio-8089-exec-2] o.j.c.c.session.SingleSignOutHandler     : Recording session for token ST-1553-4NR7XWRPXGioiJXs9oLd-cas-01.mydomain.com
2018-05-22 13:59:47.425 DEBUG --- [nio-8089-exec-2] c.c.s.HashMapBackedSessionMappingStorage : Attempting to remove Session=[7CBCC94E9BF728A044B05C07ABFAB894]
2018-05-22 13:59:47.425 DEBUG --- [nio-8089-exec-2] c.c.s.HashMapBackedSessionMappingStorage : Attempting to remove Session=[7CBCC94E9BF728A044B05C07ABFAB894]
2018-05-22 13:59:47.425 DEBUG --- [nio-8089-exec-2] c.c.s.HashMapBackedSessionMappingStorage : No mapping for session found.  Ignoring.
2018-05-22 13:59:47.425 DEBUG --- [nio-8089-exec-2] c.c.s.HashMapBackedSessionMappingStorage : No mapping for session found.  Ignoring.
2018-05-22 13:59:47.440 DEBUG --- [nio-8089-exec-2] o.j.c.c.v.Cas20ServiceTicketValidator    : Placing URL parameters in map.
2018-05-22 13:59:47.440 DEBUG --- [nio-8089-exec-2] o.j.c.c.v.Cas20ServiceTicketValidator    : Placing URL parameters in map.
2018-05-22 13:59:47.441 DEBUG --- [nio-8089-exec-2] o.j.c.c.v.Cas20ServiceTicketValidator    : Calling template URL attribute map.
2018-05-22 13:59:47.441 DEBUG --- [nio-8089-exec-2] o.j.c.c.v.Cas20ServiceTicketValidator    : Calling template URL attribute map.
2018-05-22 13:59:47.441 DEBUG --- [nio-8089-exec-2] o.j.c.c.v.Cas20ServiceTicketValidator    : Loading custom parameters from configuration.
2018-05-22 13:59:47.441 DEBUG --- [nio-8089-exec-2] o.j.c.c.v.Cas20ServiceTicketValidator    : Loading custom parameters from configuration.
2018-05-22 13:59:47.442 DEBUG --- [nio-8089-exec-2] o.j.c.c.v.Cas20ServiceTicketValidator    : Constructing validation url: https://cas.mydomain.com/cas/serviceValidate?pgtUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8089%2Fsecure%2Freceptor&ticket=ST-1553-4NR7XWRPXGioiJXs9oLd-cas-01.mydomain.com&service=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8089%2Flogin%2Fcas
2018-05-22 13:59:47.442 DEBUG --- [nio-8089-exec-2] o.j.c.c.v.Cas20ServiceTicketValidator    : Constructing validation url: https://cas.mydomain.com/cas/serviceValidate?pgtUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8089%2Fsecure%2Freceptor&ticket=ST-1553-4NR7XWRPXGioiJXs9oLd-cas-01.mydomain.com&service=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8089%2Flogin%2Fcas
2018-05-22 13:59:47.442 DEBUG --- [nio-8089-exec-2] o.j.c.c.v.Cas20ServiceTicketValidator    : Retrieving response from server.
2018-05-22 13:59:47.442 DEBUG --- [nio-8089-exec-2] o.j.c.c.v.Cas20ServiceTicketValidator    : Retrieving response from server.
2018-05-22 13:59:48.864 DEBUG --- [nio-8089-exec-2] o.j.c.c.v.Cas20ServiceTicketValidator    : Server response: 
2018-05-22 13:59:48.864 DEBUG --- [nio-8089-exec-2] o.j.c.c.v.Cas20ServiceTicketValidator    : Server response: 
2018-05-22 13:59:49.334 ERROR --- [nio-8089-exec-2] org.jasig.cas.client.util.XmlUtils       : Premature end of file.

org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Premature end of file.
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.jasig.cas.client.util.XmlUtils.getTextForElement(XmlUtils.java:192)

serverUrlPrefix  = 'http://cas.mydomain.com/cas'
```

Any ideas or suggestions would be appreciated!!!

Below is the output from my Grails 2.5.1 version of the same app and CAS server.

```
2018-05-18 10:42:26,755 DEBUG AbstractUrlBasedTicketValidator - Placing URL parameters in map.
2018-05-18 10:42:26,755 DEBUG AbstractUrlBasedTicketValidator - Calling template URL attribute map.
2018-05-18 10:42:26,756 DEBUG AbstractUrlBasedTicketValidator - Loading custom parameters from configuration.
2018-05-18 10:42:26,756 DEBUG AbstractUrlBasedTicketValidator - Constructing validation url: https://cas.mydomin.com/serviceValidate?ticket=ST-1485-7X6VirHikiEKadmDnt0Y-cas-01.mydomin.com&service=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8089%2Fj_spring_cas_security_check
2018-05-18 10:42:26,756 DEBUG AbstractUrlBasedTicketValidator - Retrieving response from server.
2018-05-18 10:42:27,204 DEBUG AbstractUrlBasedTicketValidator - Server response: 
<cas:serviceResponse xmlns:cas='http://www.yale.edu/tp/cas'>
    <cas:authenticationSuccess>
        <cas:user>first.lastname</cas:user>


    </cas:authenticationSuccess>
</cas:serviceResponse>
```

Comment: CAS, by default, needs the participating endpoints to be covered by TLS (https, not http).  I would guess that your cas server is returning some HTML error page that the plugin client can’t parse.  Try visiting your cas server directly and see how it responds to the login attempt.

Comment: Also, the plugin does not provide a CAS server.

Comment: I change the serverUrlPrefix protocol to https but continue to get the same error. I have a working CAS server with the same application written with Grails 2.5.1. I am trying to upgrade my app to Grails 3.3.x. The CAS plugin on GitHub does contain a CAS server for testing here: https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-cas/tree/master/testapps

Comment: What do you observe when you simply visit the “production” CAS server directly and try to log in?

Comment: I enter my user name and password and if both are correct a blank page is returned. If I enter an incorrect password our custom login form is redisplayed.

Comment: FYI: When I point my app to the CAS server from the Grails plugin sources on GitHub I am able to login (I ran the Github CAS server locally). That CAS server only checks that the user name and password match. My Production CAS server pom file shows version 4.0.0, I am not sure which version of the CAS client is included in the Grails 3 plugin. I also don't know which version of the CAS server is on GitHub with the Grails 3 plugin project. Are all versions of the CAS client compatible with all versions of the CAS server?